# Move sprite in a path without returning to first place in AndEngine

Tags: android, path, andengine

I'm writing a game that needs to move tiles to another positions. I use PathModifier to move my sprite from it's current place to final position. My problem is that when it arrives to final position, returns to initial position (It does not loop, actucally it jumps to first place and every thing finish). I want to keep the tile in final place. Here is my code:

```
private void MoveSprite(AnimatedSprite sprite, float tileX, float tileY){
    Vector2 tile = GetTilePosition(new Vector2(tileX, tileY));
    final Path path = new Path(2).to(sprite.getX(), sprite.getY()).to(tile.x, tile.y);
    PathModifier pathModifier = new PathModifier(1, path);
    sprite.registerEntityModifier(pathModifier);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolved it myself! The problem was that I was using `pTouchArea` argument of `onAreaTouched` event which is `final` and all changes un-done after finishing that method. I changed my way of getting touched tile and it works fine now.